# Sum of two buffers in for loop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop, buffer

I have two buffers with different sizes and I need to get a third one which is equal to the sum of the two.

That is how I'm doing it (I know it's wrong)

```
    for (i = 0; i < num; i += c){
    for (i2 = 0; i2 < num2; i2 += c2){

        printf("%d ",(buf[i]+buf2[i2])/2);

        }
}
```

I don't want to finish the i2 loop and then iterate i by 1, I want to let both for loops work at the same time and i have no idea how to do it because num2>num so if i use a single for like that:

```
 `for (i = 0, i2=0; i < num, i2 < num2; i+=c, i2+=c)`
```

I don't think it would work.

I have thought of using the code written right above and adding something like : When i = num let buf[i] becomes equal to 0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Done sorry I didn't know it should be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate until reaching the end of the smaller array, and then continue onward for the larger array:

```
int i;
int lower = num > num2 ? num2 : num;
int upper = num > num2 ? num : num2;
int buf3[upper];

for (i = 0; i < lower; ++i) {
    buf3[i] = buf[i] + buf2[i];
}

for (i; i < upper; ++i) {
    if (upper == num2) {
        buf3[i] = buf2[i];
    }
    else {
        buf3[i] = buf[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't think of that, i'm feeling dumb.
Many thanks!

Comment: One more thing, I was having a problem with
buf3[i] += buf2[i];
and
buf3[i] += buf[i];

I removed the + and it worked. I have no idea why

Comment: You are correct.  `buf3[i] += x` just means add `x` to `buf3[i]`, which also should have worked.

Comment: maybe the default value of an non-allocated value is by default something huge ?

Comment: @HanounFouad This is likely the answer.  You could have first zeroed out the `buf3` array.